# Pandas check row list values with column name

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a dataframe like:

[image]

and i want an output like:

[image]

The rows in df1 are nothing but combinations of the column names,
wherever the combination name matches with the column names, that cell will be made as 1 and rest 0

Any idea how to achieve this?

I a trying to loop through each row and do a string contains condition but kind of stuck.

Comment: check out `str.get_dummies(sep=',')` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using below code

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
for i in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[:, i]= df['index'].apply(lambda x: 1 if df.columns[i] in(x) else 0)

df
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward way (one-liner) of doing this using `explode`, `get_dummies`, and `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['a',['a','b'],['a','b','c'], ['b','c','d'], ['b', 'd']])

multihot = pd.get_dummies(df.iloc[:,0].explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()
result = df.join(multihot)

print(result)
```

```
           0  a  b  c  d
0          a  1  0  0  0
1     [a, b]  1  1  0  0
2  [a, b, c]  1  1  1  0
3  [b, c, d]  0  1  1  1
4     [b, d]  0  1  0  1
```

Just make sure that the first column of your input df is the column that contains the lists.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit hacky but should do the trick though:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((2, 4)), columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"], index=["a", ["a", "b"]])

pd.DataFrame(df.index.map(lambda l: pd.get_dummies(l, columns=df.columns).agg("sum")).tolist(), index=df.index).fillna(0)


#           a    b
# a       1.0  0.0
# [a, b]  1.0  1.0
```